# Can't Extract data from JSON returned by Google Place Search API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm fetchng some data from Google Place Search API, but I don't know why I'm not able to access data from it. Here is my code below.

```
getData = (keyword, location, country) => {
    let dataURI = `${URI}${keyword}+${location}+${country}${API}`;
    var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
    targetUrl = dataURI
    fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data); //reurns JSON data
      console.log(data.results); //Returns Undefined
    })
    .catch((e)=> console.log(`Error! ${e.message}`));
}
```

When I write `console.log(data)` This is returning the following 
[JSON data](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbbc7856)

but when I do `console.log(data.results)` this returns Undefined.

I also tried `JSON.parse(data)` but this gives me an error

> Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: you need to parse the data something like `let json = JSON.parse(data); console.log(json.results);`

Comment: need to parse that response like.
`JSON.parse(data)` before accessing `data.results`

Comment: this gives me an error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this

> `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

because Your data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you.
So you should try doing this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`